# How to cancel exit from JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to cancel application exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249596/java-how-to-cancel-application-exit)

I've set a listener for closing JFrame:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("exit");
    }
});
```

But I would like to show confirmation dialog, and, if needed, cancel closing. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        if (confirmClose ())
            e.getWindow().dispose(); // Or even System.exit() here
    }
});
```